# Не видны данные при выводе

Tags: php, javascript

Вывожу данные из базы после загрузки страницы.конечно, же title, description Не виден , ни поисковику ни парсеру вк (виджет для share).

Сейчас вывод так работает 
1) из базы получаю данные и формирую json

```
$link=$_REQUEST['link'];
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * from post where title_lat="'.$link.'"  ORDER BY id DESC ');  
                    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

                        while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  


                         $data= json_encode(
                         array(
                             'title'=>$row['title'],
                             'text_news'=>htmlspecialchars_decode($row['text']),
                             'image'=>'http://site.com/'.$row['image'],
                             'titleseo'=>"<title>".$row['seo_title']."</title>",
                             'description'=>"<meta name='description' content='".$row['seo_des']."' />",
                             'keywords'=>"<meta name='keywords' content='".$row['seo_keyword']."' />",
                             'vk'=>"<meta property='og:title' content='".$row['seo_title']."' /><meta property='og:image'   content='http://site.com/".$row['image']."' /><meta property='vk:image'   content='http://site.com/".$row['image']."' />"
                             )
                         ); 
                         echo $data;
                        }
```

2) затем на странице вывожу

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data:"link="+link,
           dataType:'json',
           url: "output_post.php",
           success: function(data) {
                $('head').prepend(data.titleseo+data.description+data.keywords+data.vk);
                $(".cok_slider").css('background: fixed;','')
                $(".cok_slider").css({"background": "url("+data.image+")", "background-position": "fixed"});
                $(".title").text(data.title);
                $(".content").append(data.text_news);

       }
     });
```

Как можно решить эту проблему? Если без js ,но как в разные места страницы информацию выводить?

Answer (score 1):

Без JS вы просто можете сделать php страницу. Например:

index.php

```
<?php

$myTitle = "Заголовок страницы";
$myValue = 2;

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $myTitle;?></title>
</head>
<body>
    Мое значение = <?php echo $myValue;?>
    И еще раз - <?php echo $myValue;?>
</body>
</html>
```

Однако, мне кажется Вы имеете ввиду что-то другое. Можете более подробно описать?

Comment: Да, именно это я и имел в виду. просто дело в том,что Ваш вариант хорош, но у меня body большой, а поддерживать такую махину не очень удобно,безусловно, если иного пути не найду,буду страницу формировать всю,но мало ли есть какое то еще решение